# How to optimize this SELECT with sub query Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing

Here is my query,

```
   SELECT ID As Col1,
   (
         SELECT VID FROM TABLE2 t 
         WHERE (a.ID=t.ID or a.ID=t.ID2) 
         AND t.STARTDTE =
         (
               SELECT MAX(tt.STARTDTE) 
               FROM TABLE2 tt 
               WHERE (a.ID=tt.ID or a.ID=tt.ID2)  AND tt.STARTDTE < SYSDATE
         )
   ) As Col2
   FROM TABLE1 a
```

Table1 has 48850 records and Table2 has 15944098 records.

I have separate indexes in TABLE2 on ID,ID & STARTDTE, STARTDTE, ID, ID2 & STARTDTE.

The query is still too slow. How can this be improved? Please help.

Comment: Please show us the execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `OR` in inner queries is messing up with the optimizer's ability to use indexes. Also I wouldn't recommend a solution that would scan all of `TABLE2` given its size.

This is why in this case I would suggest using a function that will efficiently retrieve the information you are looking for (2 index scan per call):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getvid(p_id table1.id%TYPE) 
   RETURN table2.vid%TYPE IS
   l_result table2.vid%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT vid
     INTO l_result
     FROM (SELECT vid, startdte
             FROM (SELECT vid, startdte
                     FROM table2 t
                    WHERE t.id = p_id
                      AND t.startdte < SYSDATE
                    ORDER BY t.startdte DESC)
            WHERE rownum = 1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT vid, startdte
             FROM (SELECT vid, startdte
                     FROM table2 t
                    WHERE t.id2 = p_id
                      AND t.startdte < SYSDATE
                    ORDER BY t.startdte DESC)
            WHERE rownum = 1
            ORDER BY startdte DESC)
    WHERE rownum = 1;
   RETURN l_result;
END;
```

Your SQL would become:

```
SELECT ID As Col1,
       getvid(a.id) vid
  FROM TABLE1 a
```

Make sure you have indexes on both `table2(id, startdte DESC)` and `table2(id2, startdte DESC)`. The order of the index is very important.

Comment: Vincent would creating a view with using the your logic (UNION ALL) and then query the view help? Which would be better using the function or a view directly?

Comment: @ram I don't think using a view in this case is possible because you could not push the predicate `WHERE t.id = a.id` deep enough to trigger the very efficient `FULL INDEX SCAN (MIN/MAX)`. In fact I suggested creating a function because you couldn't inline this SQL in your query.

Comment: Do you have any documentation about this issue(or with inner queries)?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly try the following, though untested.

```
WITH max_times AS
    (SELECT a.ID, MAX(t.STARTDTE) AS Startdte
     FROM TABLE1 a, TABLE2 t 
     WHERE (a.ID=t.ID OR a.ID=t.ID2) 
         AND t.STARTDTE < SYSDATE
     GROUP BY a.ID)
SELECT b.ID As Col1, tt.VID
FROM TABLE1 b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN max_times mt
    ON (b.ID = mt.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 tt
    ON ((mt.ID=tt.ID OR mt.ID=tt.ID2) 
        AND mt.startdte = tt.startdte)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) to avoid having to hit the second table twice. Something like this might work:

```
SELECT id AS col1, vid
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t2.vid, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN t2.startdte < TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN t2.startdte ELSE null END
        NULLS LAST) AS rn
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id IN (t1.ID, t1.ID2)
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The inner select gets the `id` and `vid` values from the two tables with a simple join on `id` or `id2`. The `rank` function calculates a ranking for each matching row in the second table based on the `startdte`. It's complicated a bit by you wanting to filter on that date, so I've used a `case` to effectively ignore any dates today or later by changing the evaluated value to null, and in this instance that means the `order by` in the `over` clause needs `nulls last` so they're ignored.

I'd suggest you run the inner select on its own first - maybe with just a couple of `id` values for brevity - to see what its doing, and what ranks are being allocated.

The outer query is then just picking the top-ranked result for each `id`.

You may still get duplicates though; if `table2` has more than one row for an `id` with the same `startdte` they'll get the same rank, but then you may have had that situation before. You may need to add more fields to the `order by` to break ties in a way that makes sens to you.

But this is largely speculation without being able to see where your existing query is actually slow.

Comment: This will produce a full scan on `TABLE2` which given its size may take a while. It still might be efficient if `TABLE2` is skinny (not many columns).

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - True, unless the outer query was filtered, which the question does not imply. Would be nice if the optimiser could infer a `stopkey` from the `rn` check and still use the index on `id, startdte` efficiently, but I don't think that is likely (or reliable). And your point about index ordering is a good one.

Comment: Well, in most cases the intriguing join condition would probably baffle the optimizer. I'm not sure an outer WHERE condition could be pushed and filter efficiently `TABLE2` through a wise index scan :)

Comment: It would be nice, but maybe not realistic *8-) Still, another option to consider and benchmark, though I fully expect yours to be better by avoiding the full scan altogether.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we could engineer a case where the FULL SCAN comes on top (15M rows can be very efficiently packed if the rows are small). Even if `TABLE2` is huge, we could index `(id, id2, startdte, vid)` and access it in a FAST FULL INDEX SCAN with your solution.